# How can I download HTML source in C#

Tags: c#

How can I get the HTML source for a given web address in C#?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

You can download files with the [`WebClient` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient):

```
using System.Net;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient ()) // WebClient class inherits IDisposable
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://yoursite.com/page.html", @"C:\localfile.html");

    // Or you can get the file content without saving it
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://yoursite.com/page.html");
}
```

Comment: Should note: if more control is needed, look at the HttpWebRequest class (e.g. being able to specify authentication).

Comment: Yes, HttpWebRequest gives you more control, although you can do POST requests with WebClient, using client.UploadData(uriString,"POST",postParamsByteArray);

Comment: Wouldn't it be prudent to catch WebException's around this? Maybe that was assumed. Any other exceptions or errors need to be caught with this method?

Comment: @JohnWasham - yes, it would be prudent to catch exceptions here.  Thankfully however, most StackOverflow respondents keep example code as clear and concise as possible.  Making example code closer to "real life" would just add noise.

Comment: Issue i face is that when i download pagesource and get data than if that website is in other language than my pagesource is not getting those values

Answer (score 42):

Basically:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;  // in LINQPad, also add a reference to System.Net.Http.dll

WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
req.Method = "GET";

string source;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
{
    source = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

Console.WriteLine(source);
```

Answer (score 36):

**The newest answer** 
[`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) is considered the new API and it should replace the old ones 
 ([`WebClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient) and [`WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest))

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();   // actually only one object should be created by Application
string page = await client.GetStringAsync("page URL here");
```

Comment: Suggestion: await the async methods.

Comment: @Maarten the following link shows how to use this with async/await https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020657/how-to-replace-webclient-with-httpclient/33031778#33031778

Comment: any advantage of using async calls here?

Comment: I think it is always recommended to use async whenever it is possible because this could take time, and you do not want to block the thread with the Wait() call

Comment: Thank you. Using `HttpClient` is much faster than `WebClient`.

Comment: @MartinSchneider thank you for the note, it was the overloads with `CancellationToken` that is supported only from .NET 5 and up. I updated the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 17):

You can get the HTML source with:

```
var html = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(siteUrl)
```

Comment: Short and sweet! I found your suggestion after I read Joe Albahari's example. LINQPad > Help > What's New, and search for Cache.

Comment: var html = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(siteUrl); // need to new up your client!

Comment: Does that `Dispose` the `WebClient`?

Answer (score 11):

@cms way is the more recent, suggested in MS website, but I had a hard problem to solve, with both method posted here, now I post the solution for all!

**problem:**
if you use an url like this: `www.somesite.it/?p=1500` in some case you get an internal server error (500),
although in web browser this `www.somesite.it/?p=1500` perfectly work.

**solution:**
you have to move out parameters, working code is:

```
using System.Net;
//...
using (WebClient client = new WebClient ()) 
{
    client.QueryString.Add("p", "1500"); //add parameters
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("www.somesite.it");
    //...
}
```

[here official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.querystring.aspx)

Comment: Please be careful when using DownloadString because it breaks the encoding if the website is not using UTF-8. Use instead DownloadData method and handle the encoding part too.