# How do I retrieve the HTML of a webpage in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download HTML source in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599275/how-can-i-download-html-source-in-c)

I want the source HTML of the webpage so I can parse it in my C# program.

Comment: And I want a million dollars.

Comment: @Michael Todd: ask that at "millionaires.stackexchange.com" ;-)

Comment: See [
How can I download HTML source in C#
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599275/how-can-i-download-html-source-in-c).

Comment: and the webpage wants you not to screen scrape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .net `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` to do this.  See the example code below.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
request.Timeout = 5000;

using (WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    Stream responeStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    //do something with the response stream
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

[System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)