# Download HTML file and convert it to TXT

Tags: c#, html, url

I am writing a program in c#.
I need to know if there an option to  open an URL of a site and look for keywords in the text.
For example if my program gets the URL http://www.google.com and the keyword  "gmail"
it will return true.
So for conclusion i need to know if there a way to go to URL download the HTML file convert it to text so i could look for my keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to open the HTML file as-is. HTML files are plaintext, meaning that `FileStream` and `StreamReader` should be sufficient to read the file.

If you really want the file to be a .txt, you can simply save the file as `filename.txt` instead of `filename.html` when you download it.

Comment: I think his problem is actualy downloading the page not converting it to text. Is there such function to do so?

Comment: and how can i download the html using url ?

Comment: @yoni2: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599275/how-can-i-download-html-source-in-c

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to remove all the HTML tags and then search the resulting text.

My first reaction was to use a Regular Expression:

```
String result = Regex.Replace(htmlDocument, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
```

Shamelessly stole this from:
[Using C# regular expressions to remove HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags)

Which suggests the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) which sounds exactly like what you're looking for.

Comment: i am looking to know if there a way to download an html file and convert it to txt file

Answer (score 1):

In visual basic this works:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Function MakeRequest(ByVal url As String) As String
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    ' If required by the server, set the credentials. '
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    ' Get the response. '
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server. '
    Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access. '
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim text As String = reader.ReadToEnd

    Return text
End Function
```

Edit: For future reference for others that find this page, you pass in a URL, and this function will go to the page, read all the html text, and return it as a text string. then all you have to do is parse it (search for text in the file) or you could use a stream writer to save it to a text or html file if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use regular expressions for parsing html, as html is fairly complex for regular expresions. Check out ling discussion on SO for this

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Use instead already implemented HTML parsers for this purpose.

Here is another discussion on SO where you can find a links you need

[Looking for C# HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser)

Search also on internet by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) 
{
   client.DownloadFile("http://example.com", @"D:\filename.txt");
}
```