# How open internet explorer window, navigate it on url and get her document(HTMLDocument or InternetExplorer) using c# and mshtml library

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, mshtml

How open internet explorer window or tab, navigate it and get her document(HTMLDocument or InternetExplorer) using c# and mshtml library.
The type of IE object should be HTMLDocument or InternetExplorer.

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a place for "just give me the code"-style questions.

Comment: Do you need IE?  Otherwise download the document direct, as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599275/how-can-i-download-html-source-in-c-sharp

Comment: I don't want get her document file. I want get her object(InternetExplorer or mshtml.HTMLDocument)

Answer (score 7):

If you want an interactive-automated instance of IE add a (COM) reference to *Microsoft Internet Controls*;

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
    IE.NavigateComplete2 += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NavigateComplete2EventHandler(OnNavigateComplete2);
    object URL = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
    IE.Visible = true;
    IE.Navigate2(ref URL);
}
public void OnNavigateComplete2(object pDisp, ref object url) {
    var IE = (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)pDisp;
    MessageBox.Show(IE.Document.Title);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
InternetExplorer ie= new InternetExplorer();
ie.Navigate("www.example.com");
ie.Visible = true;
Thread.Sleep(5000);//wait until page loads
mshtml.HTMLDocument doc;
doc = ie.Document;
```