# Wait for page to complete loading when running IE as external process

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, process

I have a code to open a web page in IE from my app. My app is basically a launcher.

```
 var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"IExplore.exe",
                Arguments = "-k http://google.com"
            }
        };
        process.Start();
```

I need to know when IE finished loading the web page. I have tried things like WaitForInputIdle, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: You would have much more fine grain control over IE if you used `SHDocVw.InternetExplorer`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954501/how-open-internet-explorer-window-navigate-it-on-url-and-get-her-documenthtmld

Comment: Thanks Paul, that's exactly what I needed.