# How do I find the text within a div in the source of a web page using C#

Tags: c#, html, linq

How can I get the `HTML` code from a website, save it, and find some text by using a `LINQ` expression?

I'm using the following code to get the source of a web page:

```cs
public static String code(string Url)
{
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
    myRequest.Method = "GET";
    WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(),
        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    myResponse.Close();
    
    return result;
}
```

How do I find the text within a div in the source of the web page?

Comment: Depends how smart search should be. A simple `Contains` call might be "good enough."

Comment: Look into using HTMLAgility pack, Fizzler or CSQuery to get the div/text once you have the HTML, anything else is too error prone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I download HTML source in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599275/how-can-i-download-html-source-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett That doesn't look like a duplicate of this question, the question you link to is only about retrieving the source, this question is also about querying the DOM.

Comment: @Mark: Sorry you're quite right, missed the text at the bottom.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Getting HTML code from a website. You can use code like this:

```cs
string urlAddress = "http://google.com";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader readStream = null;
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.CharacterSet))
        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
    else
        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream,
            Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
    string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
    response.Close();
    readStream.Close();
}
```

This will give you the returned `HTML` from the website. But find text via `LINQ` is not that easy.
Perhaps it is better to use regular expression but that does not play well with `HTML`.

Comment: The Idea of using regex for html or XML is VERY bad coding practice... Going in Your Way - we should use goto keyword everywhere...

Comment: Actually, using regex to search a precise thing within HTML code can be a very decent solution.
Atempting to build a HTML parser/interpretor based on regex, on the other hand, would be pure madness. It all depends on the context and the actual task that needs to be performed, but saying that "regex never plays well with HTML" simply isn't a global, unalinable truth. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/6838730

Comment: @MathieuVIALES programmers can get in a trap where they think something is simple and then it becomes complicated but they have too much investment in their first choice.

Answer (score 190):

Better you can use the Webclient class to simplify your task:

```
using System.Net;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://somesite.com/default.html");
}
```

Comment: Any idea why I get this error?
_'System.Net.WebClient': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'_

Comment: For the `using` requirement Clearly shown for everyone to use : +1

Comment: For those who are getting http 403 error, add

client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Fiddler");

Replace Fiddler with any text you want.

Answer (score 41):

Best thing to use is [HTMLAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex). You can also look into using [Fizzler](https://code.google.com/p/fizzler/) or [CSQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) depending on your needs for selecting the elements from the retrieved page. Using LINQ or Regukar Expressions is just to error prone, especially when the HTML can be malformed, missing closing tags, have nested child elements etc.

You need to stream the page into an HtmlDocument object and then select your required element.

```
// Call the page and get the generated HTML
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["br"] = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlElementFlag.Empty;
doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;

try
{
    var webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(pageUrl);
    Stream stream = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    doc.Load(stream);
    stream.Close();
}
catch (System.UriFormatException uex)
{
    Log.Fatal("There was an error in the format of the url: " + itemUrl, uex);
    throw;
}
catch (System.Net.WebException wex)
{
    Log.Fatal("There was an error connecting to the url: " + itemUrl, wex);
    throw;
}

//get the div by id and then get the inner text 
string testDivSelector = "//div[@id='test']";
var divString = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(testDivSelector).InnerHtml.ToString();
```

[EDIT]
Actually, scrap that. The simplest method is to use [FizzlerEx](http://fizzlerex.codeplex.com/), an updated jQuery/CSS3-selectors implementation of the original Fizzler project.

Code sample directly from their site:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack;

//get the page
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var document = web.Load("http://example.com/page.html");
var page = document.DocumentNode;

//loop through all div tags with item css class
foreach(var item in page.QuerySelectorAll("div.item"))
{
    var title = item.QuerySelector("h3:not(.share)").InnerText;
    var date = DateTime.Parse(item.QuerySelector("span:eq(2)").InnerText);
    var description = item.QuerySelector("span:has(b)").InnerHtml;
}
```

I don't think it can get any simpler than that.

Comment: What if I want to invoke a specific button on the web page? @jammykam

Comment: You can't do that with a screen scraper afaik, you would have to use anything like Selenium to invoke the button.

Comment: How you install  FizzlerEx? I check the link and there is a .zip but don't see any installer

Comment: FizzlerEx link dead. Also, the github page seems outdated as hell, but is it?

Comment: @wEight Yes, seems to be dead, stick with [HTML Agility Pack ](https://html-agility-pack.net/)

Answer (score 8):

I am using [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) and have been very satisfied with it.

Here is a simple example how to fetch a page:

```
var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
var document = await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync("https://www.google.com");
```

And now you have a web page in *document* variable. Then you can easily access it by LINQ or other methods. For example if you want to get a string value from a HTML table:

```
var someStringValue = document.All.Where(m =>
        m.LocalName == "td" &&
        m.HasAttribute("class") &&
        m.GetAttribute("class").Contains("pid-1-bid")
    ).ElementAt(0).TextContent.ToString();
```

To use CSS selectors please see [AngleSharp examples](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki/Examples).

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example of using the `HttpWebRequest` class to fetch a URL

```
private void buttonl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    String url = TextBox_url.Text;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url); 
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse(); 
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()); 
    richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
    sr.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: you should add code in your answer instead of an image.

Answer (score 4):

You can use WebClient to download the html for any url. Once you have the html, you can use a third-party library like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to lookup values in the html as in below code -

```
public static string GetInnerHtmlFromDiv(string url)
    {
        string HTML;
        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            HTML = wc.DownloadString(url);
        }
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(HTML);
        
        HtmlNode element = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='<div id here>']");
        if (element != null)
        {
            return element.InnerHtml.ToString();
        }   
        return null;            
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution. It works fine.

```
 try{
        String url = textBox1.Text;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(sr);
        var aTags = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
        int counter = 1;
        if (aTags != null)
        {
            foreach (var aTag in aTags)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text +=  aTag.InnerHtml +  "\n" ;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        sr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to retrieve related keywords." + ex);
        }
```