# Get Data from a Website and update a SQL Server 2008 R2 Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm wondering if it is at all possible to take data from a website and update a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 at a given interval of time?

The website in question updates every 5 minutes, changing the values of two numbers. As stated above I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I also have Visual Studio 2013 if that matters at all. I need to take these two numbers every 5 minutes and update a table I have created on the SQL Server.

I know I can use an Excel macro to do this, which I already have done, but my employer wants to bypass this altogether.

If this is possible, say via a VS application, then any helpful links or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an SSIS package with a "script task".
This task could read the website and return the information.
Then store it in your table.

To finish configure a job that call this SSIS package every 5 minutes.

Comment: Never thought of that, could you possibly provide any links that reference this exactly? If not that's cool, I can always google it haha.

Comment: Here is an example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642196/get-html-code-from-a-website-c-sharp

While you are reading the html code in the "StreamReader" find a regular expression like an html tag. You may use "Regex" class.

Don't forget to check if the website propose a web service giving this information.

Comment: Turns out that configuring a job and creating an SSIS package won't do the trick. The time interval is too short to put this into use effectively, so I'm going to try to make a service.. somehow..