# Get HTML via URL in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, html, xamarin, httpclient, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get the HTML content of a webpage via the URL in a Xamarin Forms project, but I don't know how.
I've tried to use stuff like this, but this it not working in a portable project: [Get HTML code from website in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642196/get-html-code-from-a-website-c-sharp)

Unfortunately, it's not possible to use System.Net.Http.
Someone recommended to use ModernHttpClient, but I don't know how to use this to get the HTML via a webpage URL. I can't find the answer in the example on the github page: https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient

Thanks in advance for any help!

BR,
FG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible to use `System.Net.Http` in your app. All you need to do is to install a nuget package: "Microsoft.Net.Http" (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http).