# Azure Function The SSL connection could not be established

Tags: c#, ssl, azure-functions

I'm getting an exception while this code executes, the url i try to connect is an https (SSL)

Someone knows why I get this error? Cuz I can navigate that url in chrome normally

FYI: I'm debuging this locally...

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
```

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Comment: What version of .NET are using in the local code?

Comment: It helped, the main thing that was happening is that azure by default enables ssl and that was the reason why I was getting that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"HtmlWeb" doesn't support load from "https", it just support "http". You can refer to these two links: [link1](https://docs.workflowgen.com/wfgmy/v340/html/aa27de72-b033-9883-991a-93aad0cbae63.htm) and [link2](https://html-agility-pack.net/knowledge-base/36219685/can-t-download-html-data-from-https-url-using-htmlagilitypack).

If you want to load the document from https, you can use [HttpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8) as a workaround. Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642196/get-html-code-from-website-in-c-sharp) for your reference.

The workaround(HttpWebRequest) above maybe just work in .net framework 4.6.1, so I post another workaround here. We can also use "HttpClient", please refer to the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "https://google.com";

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        string result = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        Console.WriteLine(result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it would be helpful to your problem~