# Requesting website regularly within specific interval

Tags: php, html, asp.net-mvc

I have robot which should be run within specific interval. So I want to refresh the website page that runs robot within specific interval. I know there is some site that we can sign up and that site refresh my website for specific interval. But i forgot them. I googled but did not found that sites.
Can anyone remember me one of websites url?

Comment: What i should to correct this question?? :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search "cron" keyword on Google, for instance:

https://www.setcronjob.com/

Some are free

Answer (score 0):

if your robot is about periodically checking for some information, you may find Yahoo.Pipes useful.