# How to get HTML of website using chilkat component?

Tags: c#, chilkat

it can use WebRequest but i use chilkat because it support ssh but i can not get html of my website

```
Chilkat.Http http = new Chilkat.Http();
bool success;
//  Any string unlocks the component for the 1st 30-days.
success = http.UnlockComponent("Anything for 30-day trial");
if (success != true) {
    Console.WriteLine(http.LastErrorText);
    return;
}
//  Send the HTTP GET and return the content in a string.
string html;
html = http.QuickGetStr("https://mmo4me.com/");
TextBox1.Text = html;
```

Comment: you'll find your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599275/how-can-i-download-html-source-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Web site you referred (https://mmo4me.com) is using TLS1.2 ECDHE/ECDSA for Hash Alghorithm Signature.

And looks like Chilkat component is not supporting ECDHE/ECDSA.