# How to Replace WebClient with HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, webrequest

I have the following WebClient inside my asp.net mvc web application:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) // call the Third Party API to get the account id 
{
     string url = currentURL + "resources/" + ResourceID + "/accounts?AUTHTOKEN=" + pmtoken;
     var json = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
 }
```

So can anyone advise how I can change it from `WebClient` to be `HttpClient`?

Comment: All the cool kids are using HttpClient now. This is a wrapper around WebRequest and provides an easier model to work with.

Comment: @Ananke ok so can you adivce how to change WebClient to be HttpClient ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
// Injecting HttpClient would be a better idea if possible
HttpClient client = new();
string page = await client.GetStringAsync("page URL here");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,, but will there be any problem if i replace the .Result with await in your code?

Comment: @johnG plz see the updated answer to handle the 'await' instead of 'Result' property.

Comment: @johnG I also add an update for the 'WebRequest' class.

Comment: thanks for the reply,, but why it is recommended to use  HttpClient, i did not get your point .. thanks ...

Comment: @johnG I updated the answer, please consider this answer as accepted if it is really solve your problem.

Comment: Wrapping `HttpClient` in a `using` block is bad. Please don't do this. See the link below for a detailed explanation of why. Long story short, `HttpClient` was designed to be used as a single instance throughout your application. It handles opening and closing sockets for you. By wrapping it in a `using` block, it gets disposed after, and won't close the socket like it's supposed to. This can result in the system running out of sockets once a certain threshold of requests per second is met.

https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: @AnthonyStivers absolutely true. it defeats the purpose.

Comment: I think any class that implements IDisposable should be kept in a using block and that everything else should result in a compilation error. If HttpClient wants to do some smart socket reuse, it can still do so by not disposing everything in the Dispose method.