# How to get and print response from Httpclient.SendAsync call

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpclient

I'm trying to get a response from a HTTP request but i seem to be unable to. I have tried the following:

```
public Form1() {     

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("someUrl");
    string content = "someJsonString";
    HttpRequestMessage sendRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, client.BaseAddress);
    sendRequest.Content = new StringContent(content,
                                            Encoding.UTF8,
                                            "application/json");
```

Send message with:

```
    ...
    client.SendAsync(sendRequest).ContinueWith(responseTask =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", responseTask.Result);
    });
} // end public Form1()
```

With this code, i get back the status code and some header info, but i do not get back the response itself. I have tried also:

```
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(sendRequest);
```

but I'm then told to create a async method like the following to make it work

```
private async Task<string> send(HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage msg)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(msg);
    string rep = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Is this the preferred way to send a 'HttpRequest', obtain and print the response? I'm unsure what method is the right one.

Comment: There is no wrong or right way to do this. Depending on your application, both make sense. If you are not sure, i would personally recommend the async/await approach.

Comment: There's no way to have all the code inside the constructor I suppose? I'm just testing out an api at the moment.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem with the mentioned solutions is, but you can also just use the Result Property.

var response = client.SendAsync(sendRequest).Result;

Note that you "lose" the asynchrony with this approach. This is blocking (like await).

Comment: Solution is fine , just tried to print result in constructor instead of having to create async methods, this seemed to do the trick : `HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(sendRequest).Result;
 ` `var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`

Comment: I still don't know what constructor you are talking about. Glad you got it working anyways ;)

Comment: I meant inside the `public Form1() {  } `, the code that is initially ran when i start my program, i apologize if im using the wrong terms here, still a c# beginner

Answer (score 19, accepted):

here is a way to use `HttpClient`, and this should read the response of the request, in case the request return status 200, (the request is not `BadRequest` or `NotAuthorized`)

```
string url = 'your url here';

// usually you create on HttpClient per Application (it is the best practice)
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
{
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
         var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

and for full details and to see how to use `async/await` with `HttpClient` you could read the details of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33031778/4390133)

Comment: you might want to chain the usings to reduce nesting.

Comment: Thanks for the "content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;" thing!

Comment: @FrijeyLabs actually I want to thank you to make my attention to this issue, it is not good to call 'sync over async' it can cause deadlocks. I have updated my answer to use the best practice. Please see the answer again.