# Azure Communication Services Simple SMS

Tags: azure, sms, azure-communication-services

New to ACS and I simply want to send a SMS message. The official MS example doesn't work. I get a 401 unauthorized error. I have tried to build the client with connection string just like the example and I've tried using the DefaultAzureCredential. Going that direction it causes an unknown error. Does anyone have any advice how to get the ACS SMS SendAsync call to work or let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can refer to [Azure Communication Services – Building an experimental messaging solution](https://abhijitjana.net/2020/12/07/azure-communication-services/) ,[SmsClient.SendAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.communication.sms.smsclient.sendasync?view=azure-dotnet) and [How to get and print response from Httpclient.SendAsync call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762947/how-to-get-and-print-response-from-httpclient-sendasync-call)

Comment: hi @DeepDave-MT. Well written article, however, it did not solve my problem. I have done the exact steps in your article and I get the Unauthorized error. I use the connection string, etc. It doesn't make sense why the simple code doesn't work. At this point I guess I am stuck with Twilio.

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) by "The official MS example" you mean [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/sms/send?pivots=programming-language-csharp) 2) Have you registered a phonenumber with `sms:PhoneNumberCapabilityType.Outbound`? 3) Do you use that phonenumber as the <from-phone-number>?

Comment: @rocky
1). Yes.
2). Yes I did.

Comment: @rocky Your suggestion helped. The example given in the documentation worked once the From number is update to be the same as the registered phone number

Comment: @kiran-vedula I added it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `<from-phone-number>` is set to a phone number that you've registered earlier with the phone number capability `sms:PhoneNumberCapabilityType.Outbound`.

```cs
var capabilities = new PhoneNumberCapabilities(sms:PhoneNumberCapabilityType.Outbound);

// ... register the phone number and use it in the following code:

SmsSendResult sendResult = smsClient.Send(
    from: "<from-phone-number>",
    to: "<to-phone-number>",
    message: "Hello World via SMS"
);
```

Comment: Is there any option for giving multiple mobile number in "to"?. it is not accepting an array of numers

Answer (score 1):

Do make sure that you are using a paid subscription, not a trial one as that does not support sending SMS. I spent a whole day tracking this tidbit down:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/489986/azure-communication-service-cant-create-number