URL to string variable
How can you download a webpage/URL into a string variable in VB.net?
I had used WebClient in the past, but it is deprecated and doesn't seem to work correctly.
What is the current method?
In the past I used
Using client As New WebClient
    ' Download the web page as a string.
    Dim value As String = client.DownloadString("http://example.com/text.txt")
End Using


HttpClient (read the comments in code and the Remarks section) -> GetStringAsync()

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020657/how-to-replace-webclient-with-httpclient
