# Read current artist/song from webpage/webradio

Tags: c#, stream, webradio

First off: 
This is my first time trying to connect with a Webpage so if my questions are dumb but that's just how i feel now so it should be right. :D

I thought of just trying to read out a Artist/song from a Webradio as a slow start so i can use this to learn a bit about it all.

I Chose http://www.planetradio.de/ as Radio source. Note that i don't want the song played as well. Just the current song displayed in a string....but all i find as Code are suggestions how to read the songname when the song is played as well...

If someone could give me a hint or a bit of help to get me started i'd really appreciate it. :)

Thanks in advance to everyone

Comment: is the name of the song in a html tag or what?

Comment: @user449689 Hi and thanks for your question. 
It's actually two html tags it seems. 
One with the Song: <a href="music/trackfinder.html">Songname</a>
And one with the Artist: <a href="music/trackfinder.html">Artistname</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient(v=vs.110).aspx) class. You can see some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599275/how-can-i-download-html-source-in-c-sharp).

Basically what you need to do is download the HTML of the page in a string with the [WebClient.DownloadString Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx). Once you have the HTML string, it will be easy to get the tags you want.

There are different approach to obtain what you are looking for, but I think the simplest is this one.

Comment: http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack can also be useful for parsing the html and scraping the text that you want

Comment: @user449689 thanks that helped me a lot! :)
But i have another question: 
If i implement the Code trying to get the html i get the whole "trackfinder" on the Website mentioned above. 

But i really just Need this part:
 "<span id="headerTracklistCurrentSongTitle"><a href="music/trackfinder.html">Wild And Free</a></span>
"
Is there a way to just get this part in the html?

Comment: @scitch as mortb wrote in his comment, you can use HtmlAgilityPack, it's a package that can help you read the DOM using XPATH. You can find an example and some links to other examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack I think that reading some documentation you will have no problem getting the tag you are looking for ;)