# scraping html page source code returning null all the time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-scraping

i'm writing a snippet of code to get the source code of an html page from a website
but the variable sourceCode remains null and it does not get the html code

this is my code 
 `class HtmlClass
    {
        public static string getSourceCode(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            resp.Close();
            return sourceCode;
        }
    }`

and this is where i use it:
 `private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = textBox1.Text;
            string sourceCode = HtmlClass.getSourceCode(url);
        }`

can you please tell me what might be wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with c# for scraping use **HtmlAgilityPack** nuget package or you can also download it's dll from internet this is the easiest way to done the scraping using c#.

```
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument htmlDocument = htmlWeb.Load("http://google.com");
```

then you perform all your required operation on htmldocument easily. Refer below link for the same.
[C# web Scraping](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659019/Scraping-HTML-DOM-elements-using-HtmlAgilityPack-H)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your URL is null?

An easier way to do it:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;  // in LINQPad, also add a reference to System.Net.Http.dll

WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
req.Method = "GET";

string source;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
{
    source = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

Console.WriteLine(source);
```

From:

[How can I download HTML source in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599275/how-can-i-download-html-source-in-c-sharp)