# how to get html page source by C#

Tags: c#

I want to save complete web page asp in local drive by `.htm` from [url](https://www.digikala.com/Search/Category-Motherboard/#!/Category-Electronic-Devices/Category-Computer-Parts/Category-Computer-Devices/Category-Motherboard/) or [url](https://www.digikala.com) but I did not success.

**Code**

```
public StreamReader Fn_DownloadWebPageComplete(string link_Pagesource)
{
     //--------- Download Complete ------------------
     //  using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) // WebClient class inherits IDisposable
     //   {

     //client
     //HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link_Pagesource);

                    //webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                    //var client1 = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(link_Pagesource);
                    //client1.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();


                 //   client.DownloadFile(link_Pagesource, @"D:\S1.htm");

              //  }
         //--------- Download Page Source ------------------
 HttpWebRequest URL_pageSource = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.digikala.com");

                    URL_pageSource.Timeout = 360000;
                    //URL_pageSource.Timeout = 1000000;
                    URL_pageSource.ReadWriteTimeout = 360000;
                   // URL_pageSource.ReadWriteTimeout = 1000000;
                    URL_pageSource.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                    URL_pageSource.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 300;

                    using (WebResponse MyResponse_PageSource = URL_pageSource.GetResponse())
                    {

                        str_PageSource = new StreamReader(MyResponse_PageSource.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                        pagesource1 = str_PageSource.ReadToEnd();
                        success = true;
                    }
```

Error :

> Too many automatic redirections were attempted.

Attemp by this codes but not successful.

many url is successful with this codes but this url not successful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I download HTML source in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599275/how-can-i-download-html-source-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

here is the way

```
using System.Net.Http;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string page = await client.GetStringAsync("https://www.digikala.com/");
```

Comment: Thanks,must update to vs2013 and install System.Net.Http and test.

Comment: @RedArmy Glad to help you, and please consider to accept this answer if it is solved your problem.

Comment: @RedArmy I updated my answer to solve your problem without updating Visual Studio and without Installing any `dll` (although this is not recommended)

Comment: While using the `.Result` does work, it converts the async call into a blocking sync call. It is better to `await` the async method call (no need to use .Result then) to benefit from the async nature.

Comment: dear @HakamFostok , i try witout update with webclient but not successful but update vs and successful your solution  but when save the page, no show product lis .

Comment: in url : `https://www.digikala.com/search/category-motherboard/#%21/category-computer-devices/category-computer-parts/category-electronic-devices/category-motherboard/category-motherboard#%21category-computer-devicescategory-computer-partscategory-electronic-devicescategory-motherboard/category-motherboard#%21category-computer-devicescategory-computer-partscategory-electronic-devicescategory-motherboardcategory-motherboard#%21category-computer-devicescategory-computer-partscategory-electronic-devicescategory-motherboard/`

Comment: @HansKesting your are correct, but this depends on the requirement of the user itself. Any way I am resolving this issue in my other expanded answer which I linked. you can consider that expanded answer to handle most of the cases of `HttpClient`

Comment: use the AJax For show of Product , so i want to save complete page with c# but not successful.

Comment: Good solution for save source code dear @HakamFostok but this site used , ajax or etc for show product,please see url

Comment: This solution seemed to be working until digikala generated the HTML dynamically using JS and now there is no such thing as price or other useful data in result. Is there an update for this?

Comment: @Arya you are correct, this solution is to get the HTML of the page and not to execute the javascript that is coming in the page, this answer does not and should not cover that, you have to take more steps and consult more questions to be able to do that

Answer (score 3):

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient ())
{
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("https://www.digikala.com");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient ())
{
    client.DownloadFile("https://www.digikala.com", @"C:\localfile.html");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @imbot359 , but used this code and not work for this link.i dont know that why.