# how to save a url as a html page on the server

Tags: c#, .net

I have a url and on entering this url, i am getting a html page. What i want is to save that html page on the server from that url. Here is the code-

```
 protected void one_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = textbox.Text;
        var code = s.Split(new[] { "mailerhtml" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
        string product = code.Replace(@"/", string.Empty);
}
```

In the above code i am entering a url and on one_Click of a button(one) i am saving the textbox text in a string 's'.
Additionally, variable 'code' is used to get the name by which i will we saving the html page. for eg- if code is'abc', i will be saving it as code.html
Now, i have a folder named 'HTMLPages' on my server and i want to save the html pages in this folder. How can i achieve this?

Comment: but the variable 'code' is not having any extension

Comment: instead of opening that url and saving it using windows save as option on the system, i want to save that url as html page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I download HTML source in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599275/how-can-i-download-html-source-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download a file from a URL in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use web client for that purpose it will download it and you can write a file where you want.

```
 WebClient myClient = new WebClient();
        string myPageHTML = null;
        byte[] requestHTML; 
        // Gets the url of the page
        string currentPageUrl = Request.Url.ToString();

        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();

        // by setting currentPageUrl to url it will fetch the source (html) 
        // of the url and put it in the myPageHTML variable. 

       // currentPageUrl = "url"; 

        requestHTML = myClient.DownloadData(currentPageUrl);

        myPageHTML = utf8.GetString(requestHTML); 

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\yoursite.html", myPageHTML);
```

Comment: instead of this - (@"C:\yoursite.html", myPageHTML); i want to use Server.MapPath

Comment: i am not getting this code. i have entered the url in the textbox and for that url i want its html page. @John

Comment: loll @john.. Its upto you manu whether you want to use server.mappath or any other method

Comment: nothing is getting saved. I haven't asked any complicated thing. i have entered a url in a textbox and i just want to convert that url to a html page and save it on the server

Comment: set your parameter s which is your textbox value to currentPageUrl and then try this will work

Comment: its not getting saved either coz of the path. i have a folder- HTMLPages in my solution and i want to save it there. How to do that?

Comment: @"Your Drive:\SolutionPath\HTMLPages\yoursite.html" You are giving a wrong path becasue of that its not saving

Comment: This is better that if you use server.mappath to save file in your solution. It will return you your current path and pass it as parameter to writealltext as your path

Comment: Also, what if i dont want to save the file and instead want to send it with name- "yoursite.html"   ?

Comment: where you want to send with name?

Comment: i want to bind the file to a drop down list on another page where i am sending the file in dropdown list via a mail